# How to have AJAX error direct to Developer Exception Page in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Let's say I have an ajax function and an exception is thrown in the `SomeAction` action:

```
function CallAjaxFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/SomeAction',
        success: function (response) {
            //do something
        },
        error: function (response) {
            //redirect to Developer Exception Page to show detailed error
        }
    });
}
```

I know that I can redirect to an error page with `window.location = "/Home/Error";`, but how would I redirect the browser to the Developer Exception Page to show the more detailed information?

I may be misunderstanding something fundamental here (which is a big reason why I'm asking this question), so I'd appreciate any clarification of concepts.

That page usually looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: Practically you can’t, since the error is server side and it already happened. Theoretically you could take the response you already got and show it somehow since it is the error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I redirect the browser to the Developer Exception Page to show the more detailed information?

From [this doc about "Handle errors in ASP.NET Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#developer-exception-page), you would find:

*`Enable the Developer Exception Page only when the app is running in the Development environment. You don't want to share detailed exception information publicly when the app runs in production.`*

Normally, for better user experience, we do not display error page to client user directly.

If you really want to show browser user the Developer Exception Page while ajax request failed with some error, you can refer to the following sample.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/MyTestAction',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function (response) {
        //console.log(response);
        document.write(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

*Code of MyTestAction*

```
public IActionResult MyTestAction()
{
    Convert.ToDateTime("hello");
    return Ok("success");
}
```

Test Result

*If above error callback function executed, the content with detailed error message as below will be displayed in page*

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly on Core 2.2 when I implemented and used it to show both developer and user exception page depending on the environment. I'm implementing it again in a 3.0 app but `responseText` does not contain the HTML page or any HTML elements - only raw text about the exception. Do you know what could be causing this?